# Is a field perfect iff the primitive element theorem holds for all extensions, and what about function fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, function-fields

Let $L/K$ be a finite separable extension of fields. Then we have the *primitive element theorem*, i.e., there exists an $x$ in $L$ such that $L=K(x)$.

In particular, the primitive element theorem holds for all finite extensions of a perfect field.

**Question 1.** Is a field $K$ perfect if and only if the primitive element theorem holds for all finite extensions of $K$?

**Question 2.** Suppose that $K$ is a field extension of $\mathbf{F}_p$ of transcendence degree 1, i.e., a function field over a finite field. Does the *primitive element theorem* hold for any finite extension of $K$?

In Question 2, I am actually only interested in the case $K=\mathbf{F}_q(t)$.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $p\neq 0$ and assume that the degree $[K:K^p]$ is finite. Then it is equal to $p^m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$. A result of Becker and MacLane (THE MINIMUM NUMBER OF GENERATORS FOR INSEPARABLE ALGEBRAIC EXTENSIONS, Bull. AMS 46 (2), 1940) says that any finite extension $L/K$ can be generated by at most $\max (1,m)$ elements.

Now $\mathbb{F}_p(t)^p =\mathbb{F}_p(t^p)$ hence $[\mathbb{F}_p(t):\mathbb{F}_p(t)^p]=p$. Consequently every finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ has a primitive element. Since this field is not perfect the answer to question 1 is "no". Note that one can replace $\mathbb{F}_p$ by any perfect field. Also, it easily follows that the answer to question 2 is "yes".

Comment: Great! So given a function field over a perfect field $K$,  the primitive element theorem holds for $K$.

Comment: +1: this is a fantastically erudite answer and I strongly advise all users to upvote it. Dear @Hagen: will you excuse my curiosity if I ask you how you discovered   Becker and MacLane's result ?

Comment: @Georges: Thank you for the laurels. Actually I remembered that Koch did something on generators of purely inseparable extensions. Looking at one of his articles I realized that it was built on the results of Becker and MacLane. So ...

Comment: Thanks for satisfying my curiosity, @Hagen.